# Extract Last Upper cases from a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am practicing with regular expressions in R.
I would like to extract the last occurrence of two upper case letters.
I tried

```
>str_extract("kjhdjkaYY,","[:upper:][:upper:]")
[1] "YY"
```

And it works perfectly fine. What if I would like to extract the last occurrence of such pattern. Example:

```
function("kKKjhdjkaYY,")
[1] "YY"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The regex cheatsheet from RStudio will really help you out here. [Here is a link](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/). For this, you'll want to read about what `$` does. Hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_extract_last_regex` from `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last_regex("AAkjhdjkaYY,","[:upper:][:upper:]")
#[1] "YY"
```

---

Or if you want to stick with `stringr`, we can extract all the groups which match the pattern and then get the last one using `tail`

```
library(stringr)
tail(str_extract_all("AAkjhdjkaYY,","[:upper:][:upper:]")[[1]], 1)
#[1] "YY"
```

Comment: Or you could have a more descriptive regex, for example, `str_extract("kKKjhdjkaYY,","[:upper:]{2}(?=[^[:upper:]{2,}]*$)")`

Comment: @MichaelBird If you are going with such a regex then I'd reccomend to use `gsub`. The reason for loading an external package, `stringr` or `stringi`, is to avoid complex regex